# Can we use i18n variable inside JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, i18next

I'm using i18next-http-middleware to translate a web application. It uses NodeJS and Express with Pug (ex Jade) template.

Following the documentation / examples, I'm successfully translating strings in my Pug template with this:

```
p #{t('allo')}
```

However, I have literal string inside my client side JavaScript script to translate too. This script is external to my Pug file. With my naivety, I tried the following in my JS script:

```
console.log(t('allo'));
console.log(${t('allo')});
```

Seems like the variable are not recognized. Is also took a look at *i18n-js*, but I'm not sure it's a good idea to have one method translating Pug template and another method to translate client side JS.

Would you have some ideas?

Comment: "*inside my JavaScript script to translate too*" - which script file? The express application code? A clientside script file? Something else?

Comment: Client side JavaScript. I updated my question. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: Do you want to serve localised scripts (with the translated string embedded in the source code sent to the client), or do you want to do the localisation dynamically on the client? In the latter case, *i18next-http-middleware* won't help you.

Comment: I have my Pug file (client side) where I can use translated strings, which calls an external JavaScript script (client side) where I don't know yet if I can use my translated strings.

Comment: Wait, your pug template file is not interpolated on the server?

Comment: Just started with Pug not a long ago. But it is interpolated with my server, inside an Express route like so: `res.render('index');`

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, so "*I have my Pug file (client side)*" confused me. Can you show how you "call" the external javascript?

Comment: Sorry for confusion! I call the external script like `script(src="/assets/js/script.js")`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think you should add *i18next* as a second external script (notice *i18n-js* appears to be a ruby library) and configure your express server to serve the translation files. The alternative would be to use pug template syntax in the *script.js* asset itself, which is possible but unusual (and does not allow dynamic interpolation on the client side).